# Control.DataBindings.Add in WinForms

Tags: winforms, data-binding

When a data binding is added to a control in WinForms:

```
 Binding b =new Binding("Text", myDataRowView, "title");
 TitleTextBox.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

the textbox displays the value at myDataRowView["title"].

If `myDataRowView["title"]` is then updated (directly, not via the form control) so that its value changes

```
myDataRowView["title"] = "foo";
```

is the textbox supposed to reflect the new value? Does `Add`ing the binding to the textbox set up a listener to listen for changes to the column to which it has been bound?

Or does the control have to be rebound to the DataRowView whenever the DRV is changed in code, i.e. not as the result of user typing data into the form control?

Comment: Yes, the TextBox should reflect changes in the DRV field.  No, it does not have to be rebound.  But unless that change you are making is being written back to the data source, no trigger will fire.

Answer (score 0):

When we say **updation** - there are two scenarios here.

**Update the underlying datasource** connected to the control (textbox in your case). For that look at the [add overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158436.aspx) - `Add Method (String, Object, String, Boolean, DataSourceUpdateMode)` The [DataSourceUpdateMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) property controls how the update happens.

`OnValidation` - If you have some validation rules for your control, underlying value won't be updated if validation fails. 
`OnPropertyChanged` will update underlying source in any case.

**Update the control when the datasource is updated.** 
The [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed. So for this you need to implement this interface.

Comment: Using a proper data source does this for you.  You should _not_ have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself.

Comment: The answer is in context to the question and not probably whats the best data source.